Where is the trait implementation when instrumenting a future?
I'm having a hard time understanding this simple example from the tracing crate:
use tracing::Instrument;

let my_future = async {
    // ...
};

my_future
    .instrument(tracing::info_span!("my_future"))
    .await

I'm new to async programming and this is probably a noob question.
According to my learning so far, there should be an implementation of tracing::Instrument trait for Future (This statement might be wrong, because implementing a trait for another trait sounds awkward, please correct me). Where is the implementation?
Because I can't find out the implementation, I can't understand how come it's possible to call the instrument() method on my_future.
Please help!

As a tip, because Rust has very strict coherence rules on implementations, the implementation can only be in one of two places, either on the documentation of the type under "Trait Implementations" (but you already noted that Future isn't a single type, but a whole trait) or the documentation of the trait. And that's exactly where you can find it under Implementors

There is an implementation of Instrument for all T where T: Sized, which obviously includes futures.  The instrument() trait method returns an Instrumented<T> which only implements Future when T does.
In other words, you can call instrument() on non-futures, but the result can't be awaited, making it rather useless to do so.
